# external hyper link does not work in IIS express. How do I get hyper links to reach internet?

Tags: c#, html, .net, visual-studio, iis-express

Ok so when you click a  hyper link in my web app it just adds to the URL to the end. like so http://localhost:8080/http//:www.youtube.com. I'm using visual studio .net to make web rest APIs. The web app lunches on IIS express 10. the home page URL is http://localhost:8080/index.html.

user gets links to click
[links are populated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m8Vgo.png)
error after user clicks link
[error page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gcexC.png)

```
 $.ajax(
    {
        url: "/api/Link/1",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data)
        {
            var array = $.parseJSON(data);
            $("a").remove();
            for(var i=0;i<array.length;i++)
            {
                $("body").append("<a href=\"" + array[i].linkVal+ "\">" + array[i].name + "</a>");
            }
        },
        error: function ()
        {

        }
    });

//rest api called
[HttpGet]
    public string GetLinkList(int id)
    {
        string json = "[";
        using (StreamReader infile = new StreamReader("C: /Users/jkarp/Documents/visual studio 2015/Projects/Protal/Protal/App_Data/linkObjs.txt"))
        {
            while (!infile.EndOfStream)
                json += infile.ReadLine()+",";
        }
        if(json.Length > 1)
        {
            json = json.Remove(json.Length - 1);
            return json + "]";
        }
        return "[]";
    }
```

Comment: how are you creating and displaying the URL?

Comment: I hit run and it makes the localhost for me and i make a hyperlink using a tag dynamically

Comment: you're going to have to do better than that if you want help. show how you create the url and how you display it on the webpage.

Comment: Post the code that dynamically creates the tag

Comment: @ZergRushJoe How is the json array created?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your link is malformed:

> http//:www.youtube.com

The colon `:` is in the wrong place, it should be:

> http://www.youtube.com

The link will be contained in your datasource `linkObjs.txt`, fix it there and the problem should go away.

Comment: thats just my typo. its is "http//:www.youtube.com"

Comment: @ZergRushJoe Yes, that's wrong, it's shown like that in your [screenshots too...](http://i.stack.imgur.com/gcexC.png). It should be `http://` not `http//:`.

Comment: OOooooooooooooooo sorry